# how to get String from AsyncTask Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-3.0-honeycomb

I recently developed an app for gingerbread. Now I wanted to get it to honeycomb.
Now I have a problem with my asynctask. I want to pass information (a string for example) from the asynktask-class to the activity, I started it from.
I am sorry, this is the first time I am using asynctasks and so I don't know a lot about it yet.

Answer (score 13):

The method execute returns the AynscTask itself, you need to call the method AsynkTask.get() so as to get the result of the task (of course if the result type is a String ;) ):

```
String output = new YourTask().execute(Params).get();
```

Comment: This was the solution to my problem when I was asking myself exactly the same question. Thanks!

Comment: This answer should be accepted as right answer. Please do that :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the solution is to make your `AsynkTask` an inner class of your `Activity` and if by passing a `String` to the `Activity` you mean that you want for example to set a `TextView`'s text to that `String` you can do this in the `onPostExecute()` method of your `AsynkTask`.

So let say that your `doInBackground()` method does some processing and constructs a `String` than it returns that `String` and passes it to the `onPostExecute()` method, which runs on the `UIThread` and can modify your `Activity` UI.

Answer (score 1):

Use AsyncTask as an inner class and declare a string in the outer class that call AsyncTask.In asyncTask,assign the value of the string declared in outer class.

Answer (score 0):

Rasel suggested is can be a solution and you can also simply use the getter setter method also its scope is entire project

```
public static String getStr() {
    return str;
}

public static void setStr(String str) {
    GlobalVariable.str = str;
}
```

use it like this

```
GlobalVariable.setStr("this is test");
```

and for getting its value simply use

```
String s = GlobalVariable.getStr();
```

that will return the last updated value.

Comment: Where do I have to put all that? I thought I have to do it in the onPostExecute() method.. but there nothing works.

Comment: I cant have my Asynctask in the same class i have the activity can i? because I can either extend Activity or Asynctask....

Answer (score 0):

I think the offer of Rasel is not acceptable. because Asynctask has different thread so sometimes printing any global variable after Asynctask can be done before Asynctask. so it gets sometimes null or unwanted result.